# cannot include COM reference in Qt C++

Tags: c++, qt, libraries

I am starting with QT-Designer/C++ and I am absolute beginner... 
Have a Zebra scanner library for a barcode scanner that I would like to use to create a scanner app. In Visual studio I can simply add this reference by clicking on add. Under COM libraries I find it and simply add it.
How to do the same in QT-Designer?
Sorry, in case this is a stupid question.
Thanks!

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/718447/adding-external-library-into-qt-creator-project

Comment: Also potentially helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20516153/create-com-object-in-qt

Comment: Qt Designer has nothing to do with COM. It is a user interface builder.

Comment: OK, Thanks. In Visual Studio I can add it from add/reference. I see there an item called CoreScanner. I think it is an .exe file that was installed in driver installation process. How can I open that in qt_c++ and use it?

Comment: Understood, it is just supported in Visualstudio, I think.

Comment: Qt itself is able to use COM but that is programming without any designers. QAxObject, QAxWidget, dumpcpp, lookup those words. Or, if the compiler is MS VC++ you can just use ATL technique with #import statement immediately in your code. That is complex, right. Adding references to projects sounds more like C# experience.

Comment: Thanks for all answers, I decided now to program in Visual Studio, it works fine. Will post another question on how to copy text :-)